# Perform a Click Event on detected object in Tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am using `tensor flow` in an Android app and want to do some click event on the detected object. Is it possible achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question so that it can be understood well. I also indented  the text. Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Could you include some code you already did, and also what is the specific issue you're facing? It's difficult to help you w/o a specific problem.